# If a condition is met, add entire row to a new dataframe in R

Tags: r

I am looping though my main data frame to identify where the cost of a night in an Air BnB is > 1000, it will add the entire row to a new dataframe. Currently, it is just adding one row, but I want it to add all of them.

Below is the code that I have

```
highCost <- data.frame()

for(i in 1:length(AirBnbListingsDublin$price)){
    if(AirBnbListingsDublin$price[i] >= 1000){
        highCost <- data.frame(rbind(AirBnbListingsDublin[i, ]))
    }
}
```

The row that is added to the new data frame is row 9273 from the main dataframe, but i is working fine, as it loops up until 9437, which is the length of the dataframe

Thanks

Comment: Isn't this just a filtering task? Why not `highCost <- AirBnbListingDublin[AirBnbListingsDublin$price >= 1000,]`?

Comment: You are dead right! If you want to make your comment an answer, I will mark it as correct answer! Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is really just a filtering task, so you can do something simpler like:

```
highCost <- AirBnbListingDublin[AirBnbListingsDublin$price >= 1000,]
```

Or in the `tidyverse`:

```
highcost <- dplyr::filter(AirBnbListingDublin, price >= 1000)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you insist on using `for` loop, then the code below might be the right one you need

```
highCost <- data.frame()

for(i in 1:length(AirBnbListingsDublin$price)){
  if(AirBnbListingsDublin$price[i] >= 1000){
    highCost <- rbind(highCost,AirBnbListingsDublin[i, ])
  }
}
```

Otherwise, an easier way should be something like

```
highCost <- subset(AirBnbListingsDublin, price >= 1000)
```